# Android: What happens if AsyncTask execute() is called while the task is running?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Say there is an AsyncTask that is triggered from a UI button, and the button click triggers execute() to start the task. What happens if the task is in the middle of execution, and user calls execute() again?

I know this can be prevented by checking `AsyncTask.getStatus()`, but what happens if I don't want to check that?

Comment: What do you *actually want to happen*? It depends on the version and how you have it set up but it will probably queue up another task to run when able.

Comment: why don't you try it and see..just saying.. (its going to crash though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) doc:

There are a few threading rules that must be followed for this class to work properly:

The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.

1. The task instance must be created on the UI thread.
   execute(Params...) must be invoked on the UI thread.
2. Do not call onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result), oInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...) manually.
3. **The task can be executed only once** (an **exception will be thrown** if a second execution is attempted.)

Hope this help!

Comment: Yes, I called each task by itself only once, and start new one if I want another.

Comment: And that is actually what happened after I tried. An exception was indeed thrown on the second execute() call. Thanks